# Try/catch issue - code not executing? AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, try-catch

```
private function rewriteQueue():void
{
    try{
        var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath( DATA_FILE_NAME );
        file.deleteFile();

        while (users.length) {
            var aUser:Object = users.shift();
            writeUser(aUser);
        }

    }catch (e:Error) {
    }           
}
```

In the above the while loop doesn't appear to execute. When I call the function in testing I have one item in the users array and it should be written to the file just deleted within the while, by calling writeUser(). However, once this is finished and I try and read the user from the file I can't - it's empty.

By placing the while outside the try/catch block it works fine.

I'm just wanting to know why.

EDIT: OK, I figured it out. The problem occurred when the file that was trying to be deleted didn't exist. That caused an error in deleteFile() - causing the while to not execute. Yeesh.

Comment: Next time, either take out your try/catch to figure out what's going on, or at least trace/log the error in the catch block so you know it's throwing an error

Answer (score 0):

I know you already figured it out but for the sake of the community, please give the solution as an accepted answer in future so anyone browsing the site can tell if it's answered or not (this helps both experts and learners). The practice of answering your own questions is actually promoted quite strongly in the FAQ's.

> The problem occurred when the file that was trying to be deleted
>   didn't exist. That caused an error in `deleteFile()` - causing the
>   while to not execute.

Also, the comment by LDMS is very valid. You shouldn't rely on Flash Professional's debug to tell you what's going on, using `trace()` can help a whole lot more.